# Can Xamarin create an object instance by class name?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android

In Xamarin Android, is it possible to create an instance of an object from the class name?

For example if my class is Foo, I would like to do this:

```
ObjectHandle handle = (Foo)System.Activator.CreateInstance(null, "Foo");
Foo foo = (Foo)handle.Unwrap();
foo.PartyOn();
```

The class Foo is in the same project (the main App) which is why I'm passing null to CreateInstance.

This code produces a TypeLoadException: "Could not load type 'Foo'.

Comment: The linker may strip out the `Foo` class at compile time if it looks like the it is not being used. Xamarin has some [documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/) on how to manage the linker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to qualify the namespace for `Foo`:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public void PartyOn()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Party party!");
        }
    }

    // ...

    var handle = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "MyApp.Foo");
    Foo foo = (Foo)handle.Unwrap ();
    foo.PartyOn();
}
```

Comment: That worked, as well as:  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ().GetName ().Name + ".Foo"